# Implementation Working in Python But Not in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, dynamic-programming

So I made a program that takes in three strings, A, B, and C and determines whether or not C is a merge of A and B. A merge is defined as combination of the letters in A and B such that the ordering of the letters of A and B in relation to one another are preserved. So if A = "ab", B  = "ba", and C = "abab", C is a valid merge of A and B since the first and last letters of C can be thought of as "from A" and the middle two from B. This combination of letters preserves their order in A and B and so C is a valid merge.

My program also capitalizes the letters in C that are "from A" meaning it outputs "AbaB".

I'm more comfortable with Python so I wrote out my implementation there first and then translated it to C++. But the really weird thing is that it works perfectly in Python but not in C++. I checked line by line and everything matches up perfectly but it's still giving the wrong output.

So for an example, for the input A == "ab", B = "ba", and C = "abab", my Python implementation correctly outputs "AbaB". But, my C++ implementation outputs "ABba".
The problem only seems to be with this part of the output. The C++ program seems to be able to correctly identify whether or not C is a valid merge of A and B.

Here's my Python program:

```
def findPath(array, A, B):
    output = ""
    M = len(A)
    N = len(B)
    i = M
    j = N
    while(j > 0):
        print(i,j)
        if(array[i][j-1]):
            output = B[j-1] + output
            j -= 1
        else:
            output = A[i-1].upper() + output
            i -= 1
    while(i > 0):
        output = A[i-1].upper() + output
        i -= 1
    return output




def isInterleaved(A,B,C):
    M = len(A)
    N = len(B)
    output = ""

    array = [[False] * (N + 1) for i in range(M + 1)]

    if(M +N != len(C)):
        return False

    for i in range(M+1):
        for j in range(N+1):

            if (i== 0 and j == 0):
                array[i][j] = True

            elif (i == 0):
                if (B[j-1] == C[j-1]):
                    array[i][j] = array[i][j-1]

            elif (j == 0):
                if (A[i-1] == C[i-1]):
                    array[i][j] = array[i-1][j]

            elif (A[i - 1] == C[i + j - 1] and B[j - 1] != C[i + j - 1]):
                array[i][j] = array[i-1][j]

            
            elif (A[i - 1] != C[i + j - 1] and B[j - 1] == C[i + j - 1]):
                array[i][j] = array[i][j-1]
                
            elif (A[i - 1] == C[i + j - 1] and B[j - 1] == C[i + j - 1]):
                array[i][j] = (array[i - 1][j] or array[i][j - 1])
    print(findPath(array, A,B))
    return array[M][N]




print(isInterleaved("ab", "ba",
                    "abab"))
```

And here's my C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool graph[1001][1001];


bool isInterleaved(string A, string B, string C)
{
    int M = A.size();
    int N = B.size();
    if(M + N != C.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < M + 1; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) 
        {

            if (i == 0 and j == 0) { graph[i][j] = true; }

            else if(i == 0) 
            {
                if (B[j-1] == C[j-1]) 
                {
                    graph[i][j] = graph[i][j-1];
                }
            }

            else if(j == 0)
            {
                if (A[i-1] == C[i-1]) { graph[i][j] = graph[i-1][j];}
            }

            else if (A[i - 1] == C[i + j - 1] and B[j - 1] != C[i + j - 1])
            {
                graph[i][j] = graph[i-1][j];
            }

            else if (A[i - 1] != C[i + j - 1] and B[j - 1] == C[i + j - 1])
            {
                graph[i][j] = graph[i][j-1];
            }

            else if (A[i - 1] == C[i + j - 1] and B[j - 1] == C[i + j - 1])
            {
                graph[i][j] = (graph[i - 1][j] or graph[i][j - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return graph[M][N];
}

string findPath(string A, string B)
{
    string output = "";
    int M = A.size();
    int N = B.size();
    int i = M;
    int j = N;

    for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)
    {
        A[k] = toupper(A[k]);
    }

    while(j > 0)
    {
        if(graph[i][j-1])
        {
            output = B[j - 1] + output;
            j -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            output = A[i-1]+ output;
            i -= 1;
        }
    }
    cout << output << endl;
    while(i > 0)
    {
        output = A[i-1] + output;
        i -= 1;
    }
    return output;
}


int main()
{
    string in;
    string out;
    cout << "Enter the name of input file: ";
    cin >> in;
    cout << "Enter the name of output file: ";
    cin >> out;

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(in);

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(out);
    string line;
    vector<string> arguments;
    int count = 0;

    while(getline(myfile, line))
    {
        arguments.push_back(line);
        count ++;
        if(count == 3)
        {
            count = 0;
            if(isInterleaved(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]))
            {
                outfile << findPath(arguments[0], arguments[1]) << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                outfile << "*** NOT A MERGE ***" << "\n";
            }
            arguments.clear();
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

For the C implementation, it takes in a list of test cases so that every block of three lines gives the parameters for a different test case. The first line gives the string A, the second, the string B, and the third, is C. It outputs the results into a text file giving the capitalized-A version of C when it's a valid merge and the string "*** NOT A MERGE ***" when it's not.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty sure it has to be something small like a method that's not giving me what I expect it to.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ <-- go over the checklist, then divide-and-conquer until you've determined exactly where execution doesn't follow the path you expected it to

Comment: What does `valgrind` say?

Comment: One obvious difference is that `graph` in C++ code is not reset to all-false between `isInterleaved` calls, while `array` in Python code is initialized anew for each call.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, I can't find the phrase valgrind in either of the two programs. Do you know what function that phrase was in?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tested that out and made the array a global variable in the python code but it still gives the same correct output.

Comment: In Pyhton, you have `array = [[False] * (N + 1) for i in range(M + 1)]` in `isInterleaved`. There's no equivalent in C++; `graph` still contains values from previous `isInterleaved` call.

Comment: That should be fine though because what that does is set all the values in the array as false. And in C++, by declaring a boolean array, all values get initialized to false by default. The array is meant to be changed by the isInterleaved call so that findPath could traverse it and retrieve a solution.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ohhh ok I see what you mean now. It works! Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* really an answer, but sometimes when things don’t work it’s better to start over from an easily testable MWE. I’d suggest keeping it trivial, without file I/O clutter, focused only on the merger detection and without an arbitrary hard limit of `1000`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>

int main(int argc, const char *const *argv) {
  if (argc != 4) return 3;
  const std::string_view a{argv[1]}, b{argv[2]}, c{argv[3]};
  const auto report{[a, b, c](bool result) {
    std::cout << '\'' << c << "' is " << (result ? "" : "NOT ")
              << "a merger of '" << a << "' and '" << b << "'\n";
  }};
  std::set<std::tuple<size_t, size_t>> state{{0, 0}};
  do {
    const auto s{state.begin()};
    const auto [pc, pa] = *s;
    const size_t pb = pc - pa;
    state.erase(s);
    if (pc < c.size()) {
      if (pa < a.size() && c[pc] == a[pa])
        state.emplace_hint(state.end(), pc + 1, pa + 1);
      if (pb < b.size() && c[pc] == b[pb])
        state.emplace_hint(state.end(), pc + 1, pa);
    } else if (pa == a.size() && pb == b.size()) {
      report(true);
      return 0;
    }
  } while (!state.empty());
  report(false);
  return 1;
}
```

What it does is (indeed) trivial: It records combinations of (*position in merger candidate C*, *position in merger input A* [explicit], *position in merger input B* [implicit]) achieved thus far. Obviously, (`0`, `0`, `0`) is a trivially satisfied starting point. Then it keeps trying to advance each already achieved position by one character. Ultimately it either reaches the ends of all of *A*, *B* and *C* at once, at which point *C* is confirmed to be a merger of *A* and *B*, or it exhausts all achieved positions recorded for future consideration, which means that one cannot merge *A* and *B* into *C* in any way.

(Presumably, you need to add an extra piece of data into the `state` if you want to also report a “merger recipe” together with a positive answer. It could also use an early check whether the string lengths add up.)

Now we can test that a bit (assuming that the binary is called `merger`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

abc012=(abc012 ab0c12 ab01c2 ab012c a0bc12 a0b1c2 a0b12c a01bc2 a01b2c a012bc
        0abc12 0ab1c2 0ab12c 0a1bc2 0a1b2c 0a12bc 01abc2 01ab2c 01a2bc 012abc)

acb012=(acb012 ac0b12 ac01b2 ac012b a0cb12 a0c1b2 a0c12b a01cb2 a01c2b a012cb
        0acb12 0ac1b2 0ac12b 0a1cb2 0a1c2b 0a12cb 01acb2 01ac2b 01a2cb 012acb)

for m in "${abc012[@]}"; do
  ./merger abc 012 "$m"  # …is a merger…
done

for m in "${acb012[@]}"; do
  ./merger abc 012 "$m"  # …is NOT a merger…
done
```